# Is it possible to save a File object in LocalStorage and then reload a File via FileReader when a user comes back to a page?

Tags: javascript, file, html, filereader

For example, say the user loads some very large images or media files in to your web app. When they return you want your app to show what they've previously loaded, but can't keep the actual file data in LocalStorage because the data is too large.

Comment: Are you using client-side Java in your app?

Comment: This is in JavaScript, not Java.

Comment: Do You know Firebase? Maybe this question can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955813/how-can-i-view-and-store-images-in-firebase

Answer (score 7):

This is **NOT** possible with `localStorage`. Data stored in `localStorage` needs to be one of the primitive types that can be serializable. This does not include the `File` object.

For example, this will **not** work as you'd expect:

```
var el = document.createElement('input');
el.type='file';
el.onchange = function(e) {
  localStorage.file = JSON.stringify(this.files[0]);
  // LATER ON...
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    var result = this.result; // never reaches here.
  };
  reader.readAsText(JSON.parse(localStorage.f));
};
document.body.appendChild(el);
```

The solution is to use a more powerful storage option like writing the file contents to the [HTML5 Filesystem](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) or stashing it in [IndexedDB](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/indexeddb/todo/).

Comment: It actually is possible technically, and maybe even a feasible solution if the images you're saving have small file sizes. See my answer.

Comment: This answer is plain wrong. See my answer below for several ways to achieve this.

Comment: 2019, possible solution, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19119040/how-do-i-save-and-restore-a-file-object-in-local-storage#comment97025851_19119040

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can if you just need to save small files in localStorage.

Just base64 that ish and since it's a string... it's localStorage-friendly.

I think localStorage has a ~5MB limit. base64 strings are pretty low file size so this is a feasible way to store small images. If you use this lazy man's way, the downside is you'll have to mind the 5MB limit. I think it could def be a solution depending on your needs.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, this is possible. You can insert whatever information about the file you want into LocalStorage, **provided you serialize it to one of the primitive types supported**. You can also serialize the whole file into LocalStorage and retrieve that later if you want, but there are limitations on the size of the file depending on browser.

The following shows how to achieve this using two different approaches:

```
(function () {
// localStorage with image
var storageFiles = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("storageFiles")) || {},
    elephant = document.getElementById("elephant"),
    storageFilesDate = storageFiles.date,
    date = new Date(),
    todaysDate = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString() + date.getDate().toString();

// Compare date and create localStorage if it's not existing/too old   
if (typeof storageFilesDate === "undefined" || storageFilesDate < todaysDate) {
    // Take action when the image has loaded
    elephant.addEventListener("load", function () {
        var imgCanvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
            imgContext = imgCanvas.getContext("2d");

        // Make sure canvas is as big as the picture
        imgCanvas.width = elephant.width;
        imgCanvas.height = elephant.height;

        // Draw image into canvas element
        imgContext.drawImage(elephant, 0, 0, elephant.width, elephant.height);

        // Save image as a data URL
        storageFiles.elephant = imgCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");

        // Set date for localStorage
        storageFiles.date = todaysDate;

        // Save as JSON in localStorage
        try {
            localStorage.setItem("storageFiles", JSON.stringify(storageFiles));
        }
        catch (e) {
                console.log("Storage failed: " + e);                
        }
    }, false);

    // Set initial image src    
    elephant.setAttribute("src", "elephant.png");
}
else {
    // Use image from localStorage
    elephant.setAttribute("src", storageFiles.elephant);
}

// Getting a file through XMLHttpRequest as an arraybuffer and creating a Blob
var rhinoStorage = localStorage.getItem("rhino"),
    rhino = document.getElementById("rhino");
if (rhinoStorage) {
    // Reuse existing Data URL from localStorage
    rhino.setAttribute("src", rhinoStorage);
}
else {
    // Create XHR, BlobBuilder and FileReader objects
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        blob,
        fileReader = new FileReader();

    xhr.open("GET", "rhino.png", true);
    // Set the responseType to arraybuffer. "blob" is an option too, rendering BlobBuilder unnecessary, but the support for "blob" is not widespread enough yet
    xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";

    xhr.addEventListener("load", function () {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            // Create a blob from the response
            blob = new Blob([xhr.response], {type: "image/png"});

            // onload needed since Google Chrome doesn't support addEventListener for FileReader
            fileReader.onload = function (evt) {
                // Read out file contents as a Data URL
                var result = evt.target.result;
                // Set image src to Data URL
                rhino.setAttribute("src", result);
                // Store Data URL in localStorage
                try {
                    localStorage.setItem("rhino", result);
                }
                catch (e) {
                    console.log("Storage failed: " + e);
                }
            };
            // Load blob as Data URL
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(blob);
        }
    }, false);
    // Send XHR
    xhr.send();
}
})();
```

[Source](https://robnyman.github.io/html5demos/localstorage/)