# Passing base64 string to object's attribute in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to upload an image via an input field, tie the base64 of the image to a variable, then add that variable to the attribute of an object so I can store it in my Firebase db.

Input form & field for object:

```
      <div class="row modalDetail">
              <h3>New Episode</h3>
              <table class="">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="labelField">Name</td>
                    <td><input type='text' ng-model='episode.name'></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="labelField">Title</td>
                    <td><input type='text' ng-model='episode.title'></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="labelField">Description</td>
                    <td><input type='text' ng-model='episode.shortDescription'></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="labelField">Time</td>
                    <td><input type='text' ng-model='episode.time'></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <img src="../images/placeholder.png" id="pano">

              <!-- START Image File Upload -->        
                <td class="labelField">Image</td>
                <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                  <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" id="file-upload">
                </span>
                <div id="spin"></div>

              <div class='btn btn-warning' ng-click='createEpisode()'> Create an Episode</div>
      </div>
```

The service for uploading to Firebase:

```
'use strict';

app.service('Uploader', ['$firebase', 'FIREBASE_TEST_URL', function($firebase, FIREBASE_TEST_URL) {

    var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_TEST_URL);

    var episodes = $firebase(ref);

    return {
        all: episodes,
        create: function(episode) {
            location.reload();
            //Add to firebase db
            return episodes.$add(episode);
        },
        delete: function(episodeId) { 
            location.reload();
            return episodes.$remove(episodeId);
        },
        update: function(episode) {
            location.reload();
            return episodes.$save(episode);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Controller that has the file handling for the image, etc.:

```
'use strict';

app.controller('UploadCtrl', ['$scope', 'Uploader', function ($scope, Uploader) {

$scope.episodes = Uploader.all;

$scope.createEpisode = function(){
    Uploader.create($scope.episode).then(function(data){
        $scope.episode.name = '';
        $scope.episode.title = '';
        $scope.episode.description = '';
        $scope.episode.time = '';
        $scope.episode.img1 = $scope.episodeImgData;
    });
};

$scope.deleteEpisode = function(episodeId){
    bootbox.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this episode?', function(result) {
        if (result === true) { 
            Uploader.delete(episodeId).then(function(data){
                console.log('Episode successfully deleted!');
            });
        }
    });
};

$scope.updateEpisode = function(episode) {
    Uploader.update($scope.episode).then(function(data) {
        console.log(episode);
        console.log('Episode successfully updated.');
    });
};

$scope.selectEpisode = function(object) {
    $scope.selectedEpisode = object;
    setTimeout(function(){ $scope.$apply($scope.selectedEpisode = object); });
};

// ********************************************************************************** //
// START Image Upload: https://github.com/firebase/firepano/blob/gh-pages/firepano.js //
// REQUIRED: app/scripts/js/crypto.js in index.js
var spinner = new Spinner({color: '#ddd'});
$scope.episodeImgData = '../images/defaultplaceholder.png';

function handleFileSelectAdd(evt) {
  var f = evt.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
    return function(e) {
        var filePayload = e.target.result;
        var hash = CryptoJS.SHA256(Math.random() + CryptoJS.SHA256(filePayload));

        $scope.episodeImgData = e.target.result; 

        document.getElementById('pano').src = $scope.episodeImgData; 
        console.log($scope.episodeImgData);
    };
  })(f);
  reader.readAsDataURL(f);
}

function handleFileSelectEdit(evt) {
  var f = evt.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
    return function(e) {
        var filePayload = e.target.result;
        var hash = CryptoJS.SHA256(Math.random() + CryptoJS.SHA256(filePayload));

        $scpope.episodeImgData = e.target.result; 

        document.getElementById('pano2').src = $scope.episodeImgData; 
        $scope.selectedEpisode.img1 = $scope.episodeImgData;
        console.log($scope.episodeImgData);
    };
  })(f);
  reader.readAsDataURL(f);
}

$(function() {
    $('#spin').append(spinner);
    document.getElementById('file-upload').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelectAdd, false);  
    document.getElementById('file-upload2').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelectEdit, false); 

});
// END Image Upload: https://github.com/firebase/firepano/blob/gh-pages/firepano.js //
// ******************************************************************************** //
}]);
```

All the attributes in the form save to the DB except img1. When the update button is clicked, I thought I could just pass in episodeImgData to the object (img1 variable) to save, but it doesn't save anything at all (just the form variables tied to episode.name, etc.). What's the best way to do this? I'm using parts of the FirePano example (https://github.com/firebase/firepano/blob/gh-pages/firepano.js) for the image handling.

Comment: I think this might be happening because I'm adding a new Episode inside the form by tying each attribute via ng-model, but I'm not doing that with the input field.

Comment: Are you able to upload a binary without all the other stuff? This is an even further distilled down version of Firepano: http://jsbin.com/tiyox/1

Comment: I believe so, the main problem I'm having is that any format I do upload isn't being tied to the Episode object upon saving to Firebase. I'm tying the other attributes to it by calling ng-model in the input fields, but I'm trying to find a way to do that for the image field as it's handled in the controller and not the view. In your example it sets the object with the file in the handler, but I need to transfer that data to my Uploader service so it can be done all at the same time. If that makes sense.

Comment: Can you set up a bin/fiddle that shows your problem, but then minimized to just the problem?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25209184/uploading-images-to-firebase-with-angularjs

Comment: Why are you calling `location.reload()`? And why do you call it before calling AngularFire's `$add`?

Answer (score 3):

**Update (20160519)**: *Firebase just released a new feature called [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/). This allows you to upload images and other non-JSON data to a dedicated storage service. We highly recommend that you use this for storing images, instead of storing them as base64 encoded data in the JSON database.*

There were a lot of small problems with that code.

- Since your episodes are an array, you can to create is with `$asArray`, otherwise it won't have a `$add` method: `var episodes = $firebase(ref).$asArray();`
- You were calling `location.reload()` before sending the data to the server
- Your file-upload handler wasn't triggering for me
- There were dangling references to the spinner from firepano

I think that first two were the biggest. But it is hard to find that type of problem if you don't provide a minimal example that reproduces the problem. I did that for you now.

In the end, the code is not too big so I'll share it here:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['firebase'])
.service('Uploader', function($firebase) {
  var ref = new Firebase('http://<yourfirebase>.firebaseio.com/');
  var episodes = $firebase(ref).$asArray();
  return {
    all: episodes,
    create: function(episode) {
      //Add to firebase db
      return episodes.$add(episode);
    }
  };
})
.controller('UploadCtrl', function ($scope, Uploader) {
  $scope.episodes = Uploader.all;
  $scope.createEpisode = function() {
    if ($scope.episodeImgData) {
      $scope.episode.img1 = $scope.episodeImgData;
    }
    Uploader.create($scope.episode);
  };
  $scope.handleFileSelectAdd = function(evt) {
    var f = evt.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
      return function(e) {
        var filePayload = e.target.result;
        $scope.episodeImgData = e.target.result; 
        document.getElementById('pano').src = $scope.episodeImgData; 
      };
    })(f);
    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
  };
  document.getElementById('file-upload').addEventListener('change', $scope.handleFileSelectAdd, false);
});
```

The corresponding (body) HTML:

```
<body ng-app='myapp'>
  <div class="row modalDetail" ng-controller='UploadCtrl'>
    <h3>New Episode</h3>
    <table class="" ng-model='episode'>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="labelField">Name</td>
          <td><input type='text' ng-model='episode.name'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="labelField">Title</td>
          <td><input type='text' ng-model='episode.title'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="labelField">Description</td>
          <td><input type='text' ng-model='episode.shortDescription'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="labelField">Time</td>
          <td><input type='text' ng-model='episode.time'></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <td class="labelField">Image</td>
    <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
      <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" id="file-upload">
    </span>
    <div class='btn btn-warning' ng-click='createEpisode()'>Create an Episode</div>
    <br/>
    <img id="pano">

  </div>
</body>
```

This is a working demo if creating an episode with optional image data: http://jsbin.com/roriwu/7.

Comment: $asArray is something I've been wanting to use but I implemented angularfire into my project using the generator-angular (https://github.com/firebase/generator-angularfire) from Firebase and it's using angularfire v0.6.0. I've tried migrating to 0.8.0 but I'm having a lot of issues with it.

Comment: If you have a problem, just create a minimal reproduction of that problem and share the code/data/html in a question and a fiddle or bin. That will make it easiest to help you.