# How to upload an image to firebase using AngularFire?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have been looking for an official instruction on how to do upload an image (under 10 mb) to Firebase, but I could not find one. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing base64 string to object's attribute in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25271036/passing-base64-string-to-objects-attribute-in-angularjs)

Comment: I will take a look at that. Thx @Frank

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/

Answer (score -3):

just use the input `type=file` function