# How to upload image files using firebase

Tags: firebase

I am trying to build an app using firebase as the whole backend.
The problem is I have no idea how to upload images.  Does firebase support images upload? Is there any way other than saving images to base64 string?

Comment: Firebase can store the types indicated [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/set.html). Binary files are not (yet) a supported type, so you'll have to encode the binary data into a different type. base64 encoded strings are one way to do that. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25271036/passing-base64-string-to-objects-attribute-in-angularjs

Comment: This answer should help [How can I view and store images in firebase?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955813/how-can-i-view-and-store-images-in-firebase)