# Can I store image on Firebase as file, instead of a data:url?

Tags: image, file, base64, firebase, data-url

I want to store image on firebase and want to use it somewhere. I went through [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955813/how-can-i-view-and-store-images-in-firebase) and tried [this demo](http://krumbs.net/demo/firebase_2/).

It stores images as data:url format. But I want to upload and store images as physical file so I can use it further, something like this url http://example.com/some_image.png

Can I achieve this with Firebase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The Firebase API currently does not support storing files outside of its database.

Update: at Google I/O 2016 Firebase added [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/) to its offering, which is a service dedicated to storing files.