# Add smileys and emoticons In FireBase Chat application

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I am using FireBase for chat application. I need to add smileys and emoticons in my chat application.Is it possible to do it with Firebase object.

Please help me to find this solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to store image like explained in this post : [How to store and view images on firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955813/how-can-i-view-and-store-images-in-firebase)

But personnaly, in your case, I would choose rather to store a simple string like :wink: and parse it on the client side to replace it with the correct image...

Answer (score 0):

Emoticons are actually unicode characters and can be stored by their actual value.
So for example a smile face is 1F642.

There's a wiki on that topic and I think it has a chart and cross reference on it.

Edit for completeness, some quick MacOS example code, but the concept applies to lots of different code bases.

Read a character from firebase, say 1F642, which is a smiley
and then stuff it into a string that will allow it to be a unicode char.
Then, assign that string to a text field that supports unicode; NSTextField in this case.

```
NSString *smiley = @"\U0001F642";
self.myTextField.stringValue = smiley;
```

Comment: Can you please share any document related to this?

Comment: Links often break so search for Emoticons (Unicode_block)

Comment: In Firebase how can we make its as emoticons?

Comment: You won't use firebase to store the actual emoticon. You will store it's hexadecimal equivalent so when you read it in, your app/OS will 'convert' it to a unicode character for display. I updated my answer with a code snippet and more info.