# Is it allowed to use free image hosting services for android app data?

Tags: android

Instead of spending and worrying about server level configurations, Is it allowed to use image hosting services like photobucket to save our (our own content) and use it in our android app?

**Our requirement is simple**
We have some 100s of images (photography,artwork etc) that we want to show as a gallery through an Android App.
We don't have much knowledge in server level part, Also we don't want to spend much on that part.

So is it allowed to use such websites to host our image data?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know about [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/) then you can have a look at their documentations about how you can integrate Firebase database with your android application.

Here's a [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955813/how-can-i-view-and-store-images-in-firebase) link which might help you to upload images in your Firebase databse.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any sources your internet connection can connect to. Some services may not provide convenient API, so retrieving images from those websites can be problematic.