# How do I show an image in JS from firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase

So I have firebase queries showing text messages on my web browser app. My next task is to make it show pictures, but my pictures are just showing up as '[Picture Message]"  after I decrypt the string. Is there a special function or something I need to do for it to show up in javascript like my text?

Comment: Firebase does not store media such as pictures, it will store links to images.

Comment: Well... that's definitely the preferred approach @RonRoyston. But it *is* technically possible to store images in Firebase. It has been covered a few times, so I'll find a dupe and close this question.

Comment: Travis: this has been covered a few times already, so clearly it can work. If you're having trouble, you'll have to post a minimal, complete, verifiable example of what you've done. Without that, all we can do is point you to previous questions on the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955813/how-can-i-view-and-store-images-in-firebase