# How to upload media to Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, media

I have been using firebase recently and it's pretty easy to use. I can easily store simple data like strings etc. but I haven't found anything on the internet about storing media such as videos, audio etc. in my Firebase database. Is it possible? If so how? I can also store images as base64 strings but that takes some time and ram depending on size. Is there a simple solution for that?

Comment: That is probably not the best idea anyway, since Firebase pricing options are mostly based on how much storage your application uses.

Comment: I think you should upload media to cheap cloud server not firebase it only valid for text.

Comment: But I don't know anything about servers and stuff. I need a backend solution. Please tell me a backend that provides option to store media.

Comment: This answer for most large files that require blob storage. Like @GiapLee said, AWS, Azure, or Google Cloud Storage are really going to be your best options for now. Here is an answer for images, but it really applies to any large file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955813/how-can-i-view-and-store-images-in-firebase

Comment: The exact same question was asked a few days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35682840/how-to-store-images-for-android-app-in-cloud. Please use search to see if your question has been asked before.