# Upload mp3 files to Firebase

Tags: file-upload, firebase, mp3

Anyone have tried to Upload mp3 files through Firebase. I have the following(simplified):

```
ref.push({

                titel: jQuery("#" + this._gnf.titel).val(),

                submitted_by: {
                    name: jQuery("#" + this._gnf.submitted_by[0]).val(),

                },

                  song: jQuery("#" + this._gnf._song).val(),

            });// END: ref push
```

The "song" ref should hold the mp3 files. Have been reading that you have to convert them to a base64 string. But can it even be done with an MP3 file? The

```
jQuery("#" + this._gnf._song).val();
```

refer to at input file:

```
<input id="file-upload" name="file-upload" type="file" class="file" multiple=true data-preview-file-type="any">
```

Comment: Firebase is a JSON database. Since MP3 files are not a JSON type, you will have to convert it to a supported type yourself. Using base64 you can encode any binary format to/from a string. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955813/how-can-i-view-and-store-images-in-firebase for more information.

Comment: Thank a Lot. Will look into that