# How to save images on Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase as a backend for my android app and i want to save images on firebase and retrieve it back in my app.Somebody please tell me how to accomplish this.

Comment: Have a look at this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13957446/1478764

Comment: Yup. Or one of these: https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+firebase+image+android

Answer (score -1):

You can store like this:

```
Bitmap bmp =  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.chicken);//your image
ByteArrayOutputStream bYtE = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bYtE);
bmp.recycle();
byte[] byteArray = bYtE.toByteArray();
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

And then:

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```

Good luck!

Comment: How can i save images from phone gallery to firebase and what should i use in place of R.drawable.chicken .

Comment: Terrible solution, when downloading too many images on base64 with high quality the app is prone to crash.