# Which parts of firebase are actually works with react-native and which do not?

Tags: firebase, react-native

Here the ["List" of firebase features](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O17OWyx08Cg&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLmOF_07IayrTntevxtbUxDL&index=1)

- Analytics
- Cloud Messaging
- Remote Config
- Dynamic Links
- Notifications
- Invites
- Test Lab
- Crash Reporting
- AdMob
- Storage
- Realtime Database
- Google AdWords
- Authentication
- App Indexing

However, at least, some of them don't work properly and some do not work at all with react-native.

Let's share here our experience dealing with all these services. I hope, that will clarify, what exactly FB is good for with react-native app.

#### I'll be storing summary here:

- Analytics

  - Likely supported with [third-party library](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-firebase-analytics)
- Cloud Messaging

  - Likely supported with [third-party library](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm)
- Remote Config

  - Not supported
- Dynamic Links

  - Not supported
- Notifications

  - Likely supported with [third-party library](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm)
- Invites

  - Not supported
- Test Lab

  - Not supported
- Crash Reporting

  - Likely supported with [third-party library](https://github.com/ianlin/react-native-firebase-crash-report)
- AdMob

  - Likely supported with [third-party library](https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob)
- Storage

  - I guess, now it's [fully supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955813/how-can-i-view-and-store-images-in-firebase)?
- Realtime Database

  - Web (JS) SDK does not support: offline data persistence
- Google AdWords
- Authentication

  - Google, Facebook (etc.) auth is not supported at all. Possible solutions include third-party libraries, firebase-native-sdk bridges etc. There are not well documented solution atm.
- App Indexing

  - Likely supported with [third-party library](https://github.com/igalarzab/react-native-app-indexing)

Comment: An interesting idea to track these. Please keep the list of links in a self-answer. You might want to [make it a community wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) to encourage community collaboration/contribution.

Comment: This question is too broad, and it is not even a question. It is probably more suitable to be added as Documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Check out react-native [Firestack](https://github.com/fullstackreact/react-native-firestack). Its currently being worked on but most features are supported for both Android and iOS. I recently used this react-native library for a production application for my company and supports many of the options you listed that you believed were not supported. According to the documentation Firestack provides

> Complete FirebaseModule functionality

I have used Firebase authentication, Facebook authentication, Firebase storage, Firebase database, and Firebase notifications all with the Firestack framework.

Another reason I would use this library is it contains the individual modules you listed above but in a centralized repository so you do not have to import many different libraries and deal with their possible incompatibilities and differences in syntax.

Comment: this repo has lots of errors in readme and unnecessary customizations, at least. Generally speaking, documentation is awful. This doesn't look promising.

Comment: and thats why i created [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase) it follows the web sdk, its well tested and regularly updated, unlike firestack currently. Firestack also misses so much functionality: storage, analytics, crash reporting, transactions and so on

Comment: Looks promising Salakar. Checking out your library now.

Answer (score -2):

https://github.com/davecoates/rn-firebase-bridge/

Here is another one. React Native Firebase Bridge which supports Persistent data. You guys wanna check it out.