# Add array of images to Firebase storage and realtime database using React JS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am trying to push an array of local images to Firebase store and my  database. The images are being outputted in my database json scheme but nothing is showing up in storage and keep receveing the following errors below. Any thoughts?

Error:
[image]

Database JSON scheme:

```
{
  "users" : {
    "XhLxS1KUS8UyHjsuHYrEuyipQX53" : {
      "Email" : "ssssss@gmail.com",
      "code" : "bob",
      "image1" : {
        "id" : "223d7f60-331b-11e9-b680-6b36b34d4cc6",
        "url" : "holder1.png"
      },
      "image2" : {
        "id" : "223da670-331b-11e9-b680-6b36b34d4cc6",
        "url" : "holder2.png"
      },
      "image3" : {
        "id" : "223da671-331b-11e9-b680-6b36b34d4cc6",
        "url" : "holder3.png"
      },
      "location" : "fl"
    }
  }
}
```

React JS:

```
const images = [
  {
    id: uuid(),
    url: `holder1.png`
  },
  {
    id: uuid(),
    url: `holder2.png`
  },
  {
    id: uuid(),
    url: `holder3.png`
  }
];


class Register extends Component {
  state = {
    email: '',
    password: '',
    code: 'bob',
    location: 'fl',
    image: null,
    url: '',
    error: null,
    arr: images,
  };


  handleInputChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    if (e.target.files[0]) {
      const image = this.state.arr;
      this.setState(() => ({ image }));
      console.log(image)
    }
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { email, password, image, url } = this.state;

    const storageRef = storage.ref(`images/`);
    this.state.image.map((file, index) => {
      storageRef
        .child(`${file.url}`)
        .getDownloadURL().then(url => {
          this.setState({ url }); <---Should I set state?
        })
    });

    firebase
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((user) => {
        firebase
        .database()
        .ref('users/' + user.user.uid)
        .set({
          Email: user.user.email,
          code:  this.state.code,
          location:  this.state.location,
          image1:  images[0],
          image2:  images[1],
          image3:  images[2]
        })
        //console.log(this.state.url)
        this.props.history.push('/');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.setState({ error: error });
      });
  };
....
```

This works for a single image to storage:

React JS:

```
class Register extends Component {
  state = {
    email: '',
    password: '',
    code: 'bob',
    location: 'fl',
    image: null,
    url: '',
    error: null,
  };


  handleInputChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    if (e.target.files[0]) {
      const image = e.target.files[0];
      this.setState(() => ({image}));
    }
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { email, password, image, url } = this.state;
    const uploadTask = storage.ref(`images/${image.name}`).put(image);

    uploadTask.on('state_changed', () => {
      storage.ref('images').child(image.name).getDownloadURL().then(url => {
          console.log(url);
          this.setState({url});
      })
    });

    firebase
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((user) => {
        firebase
        .database()
        .ref('users/' + user.user.uid)
        .set({
          Email: user.user.email,
          code:  this.state.code,
          location:  this.state.location,
          image:  this.state.url
        })
        this.props.history.push('/');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.setState({ error: error });
      });
  };
...
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a single file? If so, can you share the download URL for that file?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - Updated the question. I am to get a single image to  work, just not multiple images...

Answer (score -1):

As I [commented on your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54736051/upload-image-to-a-user-using-firebase-realtime-database-and-react#comment96260815_54736051):

> You need to write the URL to the database from within the callback to `getDownloadUrl()`. So where you now call `this.setState({url});`, call something like `firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.user.uid + '/image').set(url);` too.

In addition, as far as I can see from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#monitor_upload_progress), there are three callbacks for `UploadTask.on('state_changed'` and the third is called when the upload is completed.

So:

```
uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot) {
  // handle progress messages here
},(error) => {
  // handle errors here
},() => {
  storage.ref('images').child(image.name).getDownloadURL().then(url => {
      console.log(url);
      this.setState({url});
      firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.user.uid + '/image').set(url);
  })
});
```

Comment: Shouldnt the 'uploadTask' be inside my loop? I am trying to store multiple images. Not a single image