# Displaying an Image.file in flutter from firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, error-handling, imagepicker

I'm having an Issue with calling an `Image.file` from my `firebase` into my app. I tried converting it to string and so many things but nothing works.

Here is how im fetching the data from firebase: (the image its a file so I wrapped it in file)

```
Future<void> fetchAndSetCars() async {
    const url = 'https://mylink.firebaseio.com/cars.json';
    try {
      final response = await http.get(url);
      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      final List<AddCar> loadedCars = [];
      extractedData.forEach((carId, carData) {
        loadedCars.add(AddCar(
          // other data
          image: File(carData['image']),
        ));
      });
      _cars = loadedCars;
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      throw (error);
    }
  }
```

this is the data im passing to firebase: (I converted the Image.toString() is this a wrong way of passing a file to firebase in order to call it?)

```
void addCar(AddCar car) {
    const url = 'https://mylink.firebaseio.com/cars.json';
    http.post(
      url,
      body: json.encode({
        // other data
        'image': car.image.toString(),
      }),
    );
    final newCar = AddCar(
      // other data
      image: car.image,
    );
    _cars.insert(0, newCar);

    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Here is how the Image is supposed to be displayed using `Image.file`:

```
 child: Image.file(
                    image,
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
```

And lastly using `ImagePicker` to select the `file Image` from the gallery:

```
String img;

  static Future<String> fileToB64(File f) async {
    List<int> imageBytes = f.readAsBytesSync();

    return base64Encode(
      imageBytes,
    );
  }

  Future<void> _takePicture() async {
    final imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
    );
    setState(() {
      data.image = imageFile;
    });
    fileToB64(imageFile).then((d) {
      setState(() {
        img = d; //base64Decode(d);
      });
    });
  }

// the button in my code
 child: FlatButton(
                      child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).createAddImages),
                      onPressed: _takePicture,
                    ),
```

and here is the stacktrace:

```
Restarted application in 3,377ms.
E/flutter (12041): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'forEach' was called on null.
E/flutter (12041): Receiver: null
E/flutter (12041): Tried calling: forEach(Closure: (String, dynamic) => Null)
E/flutter (12041): #0      Mobiles.fetchAndSetMobiles 
package:flutter_app/providers/mobile_provider.dart:180
E/flutter (12041): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (12041): #1      _MobilesAreaState.initState.<anonymous closure> 
package:flutter_app/home_parts/mobiles_area.dart:17
E/flutter (12041): #2      _rootRunUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
E/flutter (12041): #3      _CustomZone.runUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
E/flutter (12041): #4      _FutureListener.handleValue  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:137:18)
E/flutter (12041): #5      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:678:45)
E/flutter (12041): #6      Future._propagateToListeners  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:707:32)
E/flutter (12041): #7      Future._complete  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:512:7)
E/flutter (12041): #8      new Future.delayed.<anonymous closure>  (dart:async/future.dart:313:16)
E/flutter (12041): #9      _rootRun  (dart:async/zone.dart:1120:38)
E/flutter (12041): #10     _CustomZone.run  (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
E/flutter (12041): #11     _CustomZone.runGuarded  (dart:async/zone.dart:923:7)
E/flutter (12041): #12     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure>  (dart:async/zone.dart:963:23)
E/flutter (12041): #13     _rootRun  (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
E/flutter (12041): #14     _CustomZone.run  (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
E/flutter (12041): #15     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure>  (dart:async/zone.dart:947:23)
E/flutter (12041): #16     Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure>  (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:21:15)
E/flutter (12041): #17     _Timer._runTimers  (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:382:19)
E/flutter (12041): #18     _Timer._handleMessage  (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:416:5)
E/flutter (12041): #19     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage  (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:12)
```

Im more than positive the way im fetching the image or passsing it to firebase is the issue but Ive tried countless ways and nothing seemed to work.

Comment: That exception is being throw in fetchandsetmobiles, but you don't show that code. In that method, look for the foreach. It's getting called on null.

Comment: I have 2 fetch methods 1 for  cars and 1 for mobiles both work the same way and give the same error

Comment: Are you sure that extractedData is valid? Can you print it before using it?

Comment: do i print it by calling print(response.body)?

Comment: and/or `print(extractedData)`

Comment: it works fine it prints all the data even the image file path that is converted to string because that was the only way I was able to upload the File data to Firebase

Comment: good - now add the code from my answer and `print(loadedCars)` too

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using [firebase storage](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_storage) rather than firebase database for images. See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13957446/8213910). Once you've got an instance firebase storage and a storage reference, it should be as simple as calling a method on that reference.

Edit: Here's some untested code that shows one way.

```dart
import 'package:approachbuilder/models/profile.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;

final FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage();
final StorageReference storageReference = firebaseStorage.ref();

class UserProfileImage extends StatelessWidget {
  UserProfileImage(this.userDocument);

  /// The current user's profile document in firebase
  /// gotten through Firestore.instance.collection('users).document(userId);
  final DocumentReference userDocument;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<Profile>(
      // Unnecessary step, maps the raw profile into a class intance
      // that uses a JsonSerializable and FunctionalData model
      stream: userDocument
          .snapshots()
          .map((snapshot) => Profile.fromJson(snapshot.data)),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();

        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => _getAndSetImage(snapshot.data),
          // Traditional NetworkImage doesn't handle errors that well
          child: CachedNetworkImage(
            imageUrl: snapshot.data.photoUrl,
            placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
            errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void _getAndSetImage(Profile profile) async {
    final imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

    if (imageFile == null) return;

    final baseImageFileName = path.basename(imageFile.path);
    final imageRef = storageReference.child(baseImageFileName);
    final uploadTask = imageRef.putFile(imageFile);

    await uploadTask.onComplete.then((snapshot) async {
      // File has been successfully added to firebase storage
      final downloadUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();

      // Remove previous photoUrl from fb storage if there is one
      await deleteFirebaseResource(profile.photoUrl);

      await userDocument.setData(
        profile.copyWith(photoUrl: downloadUrl).toJson(),
      );
    });
  }

  Future<void> deleteFirebaseResource(String url) async {
    StorageReference storageRef =
        await firebaseStorage.getReferenceFromUrl(url);

    if (storageRef == null) return;

    await storageRef.delete();
  }
}
```

Comment: does that mean i can remove the `'image': car.image.toString(),` im passing to the database? that way its giving a file path but im sure thats not the best way of passing it and as for when im fetching that data im calling it like this `image: File(carData['image']),`

Comment: Yeah, so the `'image': car.image.toString()` would create a field in fb database with a base64 image I'm guessing. Rather than using fb database to house the actual image data, house it in fb storage and instead, write the `downloadUrl` in fb database. That'lll just be a plain url pointing to your fb storage. When you want to display that image, it'll be a plain `NetworkImage(downloadUrl)`

Comment: If that doesn't clear it up, let me know and i can add more example code

Comment: sorry for the late reply! but yeah could you please provide a little bit of more code?

Comment: also if i try to Change the display to `NetworkImage(downloadUrl)` can you provide a snippet of that? cuz I think itll give an error since the Image is set as `File`

Comment: I added a some untested code. The NetworkImage is only ever loading from urls and not files in my example. You can load from a base64 image string using `Image.memory(base64Decode(_fileString))` as you have in your code