# How to save and retrieve images in firebase real time data base with react native mobile app?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-firebase

I am trying to save the data in the firebase real-time database using the `set()` method. I can save the name of food and id successfully. But unable to save the images. Meantime I have to retrieve the saved data into the flat list. Can you pls help me to save the image data in firebase in realtime?

Here is the button with `onPress()` for passing parameters to the `addtofavorites()`

```
<TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={() =>
                    addToFavourites(item.menuId, item.name, item.photo)
                  }>
```

Here is the database method

```
 //Database
  const addToFavourites = async (id, foodname, image) => {
    //get current user
    var user = await auth().currentUser.uid;

    //get Unique key
    var databaseRef = await database().ref(user).child('favourites').push();

    //update the details
    databaseRef.set({
      menuId: id,
      name: foodname,
      image: image,
    });
  };
```

Comment: You should take a look at another answer. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955813/firebase-storage-how-to-store-and-retrieve-images

Comment: Images should likely be stored in Storage and not RTDB. You can store the meta info about the image in the database. There are a number of [example apps and codelabs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/samples/) that can walk you through storing images.