# How can I serialize an input File object to JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, file

I want to convert an HTML input file to a JSON string like this:

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(file);
console.log( file );
console.log( jsonString );
```

Now, in my Firebug it logs as:

```
File { size=360195, type="image/jpeg", name="xyz.jpg", mehr...} 
Object {}
```

Why is the `jsonString` empty?

Background info: I want to send the file-reference with JSONP to another PHP server.

Additional Information: I want to convert only the file-pointer (reference) to a string, to send it via GET.

Answer (score 32):

It is not possible to directly convert a [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object into JSON using `JSON.stringify` in Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

You can make a work around to convert `File` object to string using `JSON.stringify`

Ex:

```
// get File Object  
var fileObject = getFile();

// reCreate new Object and set File Data into it
var newObject  = {
   'lastModified'     : fileObject.lastModified,
   'lastModifiedDate' : fileObject.lastModifiedDate,
   'name'             : fileObject.name,
   'size'             : fileObject.size,
   'type'             : fileObject.type
};  
 
// then use JSON.stringify on new object
JSON.stringify(newObject);
```

You can also add the [`toJSON()` behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON()_behavior) to your `File` object

EX:

```
// get File Object  
var fileObject = getFile();

// implement toJSON() behavior  
fileObject.toJSON = function() { return {
   'lastModified'     : myFile.lastModified,
   'lastModifiedDate' : myFile.lastModifiedDate,
   'name'             : myFile.name,
   'size'             : myFile.size,
   'type'             : myFile.type 
};}  
 
// then use JSON.stringify on File object
JSON.stringify(fileObject);
```

**Note**: send a `File` Object to server using the `POST` HTTP method.

Comment: Actually, in Chrome you cannot stringify a `File` object either.

Comment: yes, Now I had test `JSON.stringify` with `File` Object in chrome and does not work. But I had test it when I answer this question was work

Comment: Uh... what? The File API was not meant to be convertible to a String. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19119040/how-do-i-save-and-restore-a-file-object-in-local-storage

Comment: @williamle8300 your miss the part of Question that say he want to send `File` Object as JSON request to `PHP` server So that he want to Stringify `File` Object.
the Question link which you put it, ask for another case also the accept answer say: (you can't serialize `File` Object) -> (same problem of this Question).
my answer is Just workaround to Stringify `File` Object

Comment: Stringfying and Serializing are synonyms

Comment: @williamle8300 yes i known, my answer to solve the case of this question.

Comment: @InsanelyADHD as I had comment on previous comment about serializing topic before [Here => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24139216/js-input-file-to-json-with-for-example-json-stringify/29281243#comment53599554_29281243], on comment I mention about my solution was not for serializing `File` Object But convert `File` Object to String Only like the question needs(The Same Problem I had face too) !!! Thanks for down vote.

Answer (score 11):

You have to read the file content using the [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader). The File object does not contain the file content (it is just a pointer toward the file, which allows you to read it later).

You can check out this [HTML5Rocks article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) to find out more about the usage of this API.

```
var file = getAFile( );

var success = function ( content ) {
  console.log( JSON.stringify( content ) ); }

var fileReader = new FileReader( );
fileReader.onload = function ( evt ) { success( evt.target.result ) };
fileReader.readAsText( file );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to send the pointer to another server. So I have to convert the file-pointer to a string. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Did you read the article ? `evt.target.result` is a string containing the file content. Using the FileReader API is the only way to fetch it, for security reasons.

Comment: I think this is not the solution in my project. There is a problem because I will send the string with GET. The size of the string is too long if the file is for example 500 MB.

Comment: Well, then don't send it using GET? I'm not sure to understand what you want. If you just need to post a file, do it with [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) rather than JSON, since the former can streamline a file upload without requiring to buffer its content in the RAM.

Comment: You cannot send files via GET. POST is the way here, I don't understand why you would prefer using GET. A web server will never be willing to parse a 500Mo URL.

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone is still looking for a solution to this please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42124123/6451718) on a different post and [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/tammyprodev/t2weuuxn/) on JSFiddle.

JS:

```
function getFiles(){
    var files = document.getElementById("myFiles").files;
    var myArray = [];
    var file = {};

    console.log(files); // see the FileList

    // manually create a new file obj for each File in the FileList
    for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){

      file = {
          'lastMod'    : files[i].lastModified,
          'lastModDate': files[i].lastModifiedDate,
          'name'       : files[i].name,
          'size'       : files[i].size,
          'type'       : files[i].type,
      } 

      //add the file obj to your array
      myArray.push(file)
    }

    //stringify array
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myArray));
}
```

HTML:

```
<input id="myFiles" type="file" multiple onchange="getFiles()" />
```

Comment: How am i supposed to get the file from this **file** object in backend?

Answer (score 4):

You just need a custom replacer:

```
function stringify(obj) {
    const replacer = [];
    for (const key in obj) {
        replacer.push(key);
    }
    return JSON.stringify(obj, replacer);
}

const json = stringify(file);
console.log(file);
console.log(json);
```

Now you should see:

```
File {name: "xyz.jpg", type: "image/jpeg", size...}
'{"name":"xyz.jpg","type":"image/jpeg","size"...}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping through, or rather extracting each key one after the other, i came up with this function and i've used it image input.

```
const fileObject = e.target.files[0];
```

**important notice**

```
//dont use shorthand for of loop
for (const [key, value] in Object.entries(x)) 
it can't loop through a file object in JS
```

*Use this code instead*

```
const imageObject = {};

for (const key in fileObject) {
    const value = fileObject[key];
    const notFunction = typeof value !== "function";
    notFunction && (imageObject[key] = value);
}

console.log(imageObject) // => should give you a normal JS object now
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the file to a base64 string and then you can serialize it to json. Was stuck on this problem and took the following approach:

The function to convert to string:

```
function fileToBase64(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result.split(",")[1]); // Extracting the Base64 string from the data URL
    reader.onerror = reject;
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When you pass a json string Javascript internally trnsform it to Json object and hence no need to parse it.

follow steps in case of of json file   ->

```
$('#inp_import_template')[0].files[0]
```

Now your json file is transformed to json object (Javascript).

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score -3):

```
var obj = {
  name: 'dashu3f'
};

var stringObj = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log(typeof stringObj);
console.log(stringObj);
```

open terminal this Folder file and run **node json.js**