# Javascript array prints only strings, but i want to print objects

Tags: jquery

I am a new programmer. I found many solution regarding this issue but failed to solve my problem.
I am trying to upload multiple images in web.

The HTML:

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="uploadcertbtn[]"  />
```

I append dynamic number or rows below the above row in this way, so I have multiple `input type=file button`, The JS for this purpose:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#addrow').click(function () {
    $('.tbody').append("  <tr ><td ><input type='file'  multiple='multiple' name='uploadcertbtn[]'  /></td></tr> ");
  });
});
```

Javascript to add file objects in a variable:

```
var $certimages = [];

$("input[name='uploadcertbtn[]']").each(function(){
  for(var i=0;i<$(this).get(0).files.length;++i){
    $certimages.push($(this).get(0).files[i]);
  }
});
```

I Test the $certimages array value in this way and it is printing file objects properly.

```
for(var i=0; i<$certimages.length; i++){
  console.log($certimages[i]);
}
```

Then I made a FormData object and append the variable in this way:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('certificateImagesArray[]', $certimages );
```

Then I tried to print the formdata values in this way but $certimages variable prints only:

```
[object File],[object File]
```

Code to print the formdata values:

```
for (var value of formData.values()) {console.log(value);}
```

Please help me to print the file object properly.

Comment: Try `for (var value of formData.values()) {console.log(JSON.stringify(value));}` to console.log the objects content as strings... If that is the question (since I'm not sure). Read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: i tried but it prints the same as before.

Comment: @robin stop being afraid of json and grasp the thiny [beast](http://json.org/). JSON was made simple and the spec can fit on a contact card.

Comment: The thing is that the `objects` you handle ARE using the JSON structure... That's why stringify works on it. There is no fear to have in learning some more. ;)

Comment: i tried JSON.stringify() but it prints the same string as before but i want to print the File object which i want to upload to database via java code later.

Comment: If it prints the same... I guess the script is in an external `.js` file and you did not clear the cache.

Comment: @ Louys Patrice Bessette i used internal .js script:)

Comment: After a bit reading on it, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42126092/2159528), which could interest you.

Comment: I am grateful to you @Louis. but which i need is to get a File{......}object in the console.