# Save Image File to firebase / save image File data into plain javascript Object

Tags: javascript, firebase, redux

So I am trying to save the image file in firebase database with redux form input but I am getting an error, `Data must be an object, but it was: a custom File object` 
till now i tried :

```
const PictureData = values.attach_picture
```

and its giving me output as follow

```
         File {
         name: "zendex.jpeg",
         lastModified: 1564032545425,
         lastModifiedDate: Thu Jul 25 2019 10:59:05 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),
         webkitRelativePath: "", size: 3498, 
…}
```

so how to save this as an OBJECT?

Question: How to save an image data as js Object so I can save it in firebase database

Comment: i am not quite sure what you are trying to achive, but to upload image to firebase you should use firebase storage and it will send you back url of image that you can use

Comment: i think that you cant store file to firestore

Comment: this currently is not an object it is a file

Comment: yes I want to convert a file to js object

Comment: what is that you want to do with it... try to stringify it somehow and check : http://blog.brew.com.hk/working-with-files-in-javascript/        maybe it helps

Comment: do you want to display uploaded image of you want to store it database?

Comment: I just want to store it into firebase

Comment: use firebase storage that is recomended way to do it and then store url you receive in firebase database

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files

Comment: Thanks @mladen Skrbic  , I already know "firebase storage" and have working code for this. BUT i want to work my way with "js-object"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24139216/js-input-file-to-json-with-for-example-json-stringify      try this

Answer (score 0):

So I had to reCreate a newObject and then set FileData into it

```
let file = {
    'lastMod'    : values.attach_picture.lastModified,
    'lastModDate': values.attach_picture.lastModifiedDate,
    'name'       : values.attach_picture.name,
    'size'       : values.attach_picture.size,
    'type'       : values.attach_picture.type,
    }
```

Comment: But its still, not an optimal solution