# how to turn multiple files into base64 string?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, base64

i have a component like this

```
<input type="file" multiple @change="toBase64Handler($event)">

<script>
 data() {
  return {
     files: [],
   }
 },
 methods: {
  tobase64Handler(event) {
   // the code
  }
 }
</script>
```

and i would like to turn all of the selected files into base64 string something like this:

```
files: [
  {
   selectedFile: 'ajsdgfauywdljasvdajsgvdasdo1u2ydfouayvsdlj2vo8ayasd...'
  },
  {
   selectedFile: 'askdhgoiydvywdljasvdajsgvdasdo1u2ydfoakjgsfdjagswsd...'
  },
  {
   selectedFile: '12edashjvlsljasvdajsgvdasdo1u2ydfouayvsdlj2vo8ayfsd...'
  },
]
```

how do i achieve that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert file to base64 in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280818/how-to-convert-file-to-base64-in-javascript)

Comment: i cant seem to access the index of the FileList :/

Answer (score 8):

You can loop though the files call a helper method `toBase64`, push all `Promises` to an array and resolve all of them:

```
  toBase64(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
      reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
    });
  };

  async tobase64Handler(files) {
    const filePathsPromises = [];
    files.forEach(file => {
      filePathsPromises.push(this.toBase64(file));
    });
    const filePaths = await Promise.all(filePathsPromises);
    const mappedFiles = filePaths.map((base64File) => ({ selectedFile: base64File }));
    return mappedFiles;
  }
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks Simon!

Comment: Very cool, never used a Promise inline like `await Promise.all()`. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

this should do the trick: `JSON.stringify(files)` you can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). If you later want to turn it back into the original array, object, or value then you'd do `JSON.parse(files)`. you can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

UPDATE: turns out I was wrong and JSON.stringify/parse don't work with files(thanks for the info @patrick evans).
found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24139216/js-input-file-to-json-with-for-example-json-stringify) which seems better (the one by @ahmed hamdy)

Comment: `JSON.stringify` does not transform File/Blob objects into base64 encoded strings of their contents. Nor conversely will `JSON.parse` parse a base64 string and turn it into a File/Blob