# JSON.stringify sends empty object from FileList to server

Tags: javascript, ajax, flask

Without a `form` I am trying to post multiple files to my server using AJAX.

This is the input file

```
<input id="images_input" type="file" name="images" multiple="" class="inputFileHidden">
```

The result I receive after pressing on the submit button is a `FileList`, as shown down below.

[image]

I `stringify` my `File` objects and sending my data through a `FormData` object under the `picture_files` key.

```
var data = new FormData()
files = document.getElementById('images_input').files
...
Array.from(files).forEach(file => data.append('picture_files', JSON.stringify(file)))
```

The problem I have on my **Server Side** after I request the key from the `request.form` object is that I get an empty object

```
images = request.form['picture_files']
print(images) # result is {}
```

Any hints on how I can safely `JSON.stringify` my javascript objects to my server?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24139216/js-input-file-to-json-with-for-example-json-stringify) answer your question?

Comment: @gre_gor close enough..interesting approach. Didn't know that the Files were actually pointers. Thanks for the insight

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply convert a file object into JSON.

You *could* use [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to read the file, convert it into a string (e.g. using Base64 encoding), put that string in an object, then encode the object as JSON. This would be complicated and inefficient.

It would be far simpler to just put the file object into the FormData as it is.

```
Array.from(files).forEach(file => data.append('picture_files', file))
```

Comment: By doing that I can't retrieve my files by accessing `request.form['picture_files']`, quite interesting..but if I leave it as it was, it works. This being the stacktrace `400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'picture_files'`

Comment: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/

Comment: I've changed my code to `images = request.files.getlist('images_input')` which works, but it returns an empty list now `[]`. That makes sense since the `File` objects are not objects, but pointers. So I don't think this method would work, my humble opinion.