# Trouble with react hook form, using file as input

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms

I have a form ingesting some strings and a file. The strings are working correctly, but whenever I check to see if the file has been registered correctly, it's always null.

The interface I'm using:

```
export interface myDetail {
  myText: string;
  Picture?: File;
}
```

Form group for image (not working):

```
<Form
     onSubmit={handleSubmit((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        setDetail({ ...myDetail, ...data });
     })}
  >
     <Form.Group controlId="formFile" className="mb-3">
         <Form.Label>Upload Picture</Form.Label>
         <Form.Control as="input" type="file" {...register('Picture')} />
      </Form.Group>
```

button:

```
<AsyncButton type="submit">Save</AsyncButton>
```

The string variables get assigned fine, but when I check data, the Picture is set to `"0, {}"`

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the `Form.***` component is, so I think it's difficult to answer.
Can it be reproduced with code-sandobox etc.?

If `Form.Control` is built as a **controlled-component**,
you should be able to successfully connect to RHF using `useController` or `Controller`.

- https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller
- https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller

Answer (score 0):

JSON.stringify does not parse File objects. Your data is most likely a FileList containing one File object, hence the "0,{}". 0th index in the array, containing an unserializable File object.

If you break at your console.log(data) and examine the data in a debugger, you'll most likely see your File object as expected. The data is there, but not being displayed to the console. Please see this post for more info:

[How can I serialize an input File object to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24139216/how-can-i-serialize-an-input-file-object-to-json)

Alternatively, you can use FileReader to read the File using readAsDataURL().