# How to store object with files to localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, file-upload

I am trying to find a way how to store form data in local storage to show them even if user refresh page. For whole form it is no problem, but I have object with image files as part of form and I am not able to find the way how to store it.

My data object is for ex. like this:

`{file_9wyh8: File, file_cwjg0: File}`

My output after get data from localstorage is without files:

`{file_9wyh8: {…}, file_cwjg0: {…}}`

I need to store `data` object bcz, there are files ordered as user see them on page. Due to this it is not possible to use directly filereader.

And this is my code:

```
// The unload event is sent to the window element when the user navigates away from the page for ex. page refresh
$(window).on('unload', function() {

// Save values of form fields to local storage
$(':file, :checkbox, select, textarea, input').each(function() {

    // Due to JS added input instead of select, need to get value from input + add to storage just checked items
    if ( !$(this).hasClass('add-item__select') && !$(this).is(':checkbox') && !$(this).is(':file') ) {

        // Save value of field to local storage
        localStorage.setItem($(this).attr('name'), $(this).val());

    } else if ( $(this).is(':checked') && !$(this).is(':file') ) {

        // Save just name of checkbox which is checked
        localStorage.setItem($(this).attr('name'), $(this).val());

    } else if ( $(this).is(':file') ) {
            
        dataToString = JSON.stringify(data);    
            
        localStorage.setItem('file', dataToString);
        
    }

})

});


// Get values form local storage if page is refreshed
$(window).on('load', function() {

// Save values of form fields to local storage
$(':file, :checkbox, select, textarea, input').each(function() {

    // If input has this class then do not save value
    if ( !$(this).hasClass('add-item__select') && ( !$(this).is(':checkbox' ) && !$(this).is(':file') ) ) {

        // Get value of field
        fieldValue = localStorage.getItem($(this).attr('name'));

        // Show value of field if fieldValue is not empty
        if (fieldValue !== 'null') $(this).val(fieldValue);

        $(this).addClass('black-text');

    // Done action just for checkbox
    } else if ( $(this).is(':checkbox') && !$(this).is(':file') ) {

        // Get value of field
        fieldValue = localStorage.getItem($(this).attr('name'));

        // If chekcbox name is same as saved in local storage then set as checked
        if ( fieldValue === $(this).val() ) $(this).prop('checked', true);

        // Remove checkbox value in localstorage each time - bcz of change checked checkboxes
        localStorage.removeItem(fieldValue);

    } else if ( $(this).is(':file') ) {

        // Get whole object data from localstorage
        
        var dataStringFromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem('file');
        var dataFromLocalStorage = JSON.parse(dataStringFromLocalStorage);

        console.log(dataFromLocalStorage);
        
        $.each(dataFromLocalStorage, function(index, value) {
            /*
            // create temp url to img object for creating thumbnail and append img with temp src to thumbnail__wraper div
            $('.thumbnail__wrapper').append('<div class="thumbnail" id="file_'+ mark +'"><img class="imageThumb" src="' + url + '" title="' + upload.name + '"/><br/><a class="remove">Zmazať</a></div>');
            $('.add-item__add-photo-btn-area').find('p').hide();
            // set up first image as main image - marked by label
            var firstImg = $('.thumbnail__wrapper').children().first();
            $('<p class="main-img">Hlavná fotka</p>').appendTo(firstImg);

            // Change photo number status
            $('#photo-num').text('Fotky ' + count + '/50');
            */
        })
    }

})
```

I tried also alternatives found in this question, but it did not help me.
[How can I serialize an input File object to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24139216/how-can-i-serialize-an-input-file-object-to-json)

Comment: Browsers have a limit of 5MB for local storage. You'll hit that quickly with image files. Maybe better to save the form with images silently to the server to a temporary space, and load that on page refresh.

Comment: Do you think to save images as session? Or some another approach? I do not have any experiences with this type of problem. I would like to use best used solution.

Comment: Yes, it needs to be based on the session for privacy reasons, and to not clobber each other's data