# Using ES6 spread operator on File Object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, spread-syntax

Example:

```
console.log(file)
// File object with properties

const f = {...file}
console.log(f)
// empty Object

file.id = 'abcdef'
const ff = {...file}
console.log(ff)
// Object with only property {id: 'abcdef'}
```

Anyone can explain or send me a reference link

Comment: can you share what `file` looks like? is it a real object or just a stringify json?

Comment: It's Web API object https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File.

Comment: [There is no standard way to serialize a `File`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19198817/3148807) hence i think there is no way to spread it.

Comment: The reason is that this object's properties are not enumerable. But what is your use case exactly?