# What is the reason for not spread (es 6 spread operator) javascript Error object

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to spread the Javascript **Error** object(Standard built-in objects). I'm getting the empty object as output.

```
let error = new Error('error');
console.log({...error});
```

output:

```
{}
```

What is the reason for not spreading the Error object?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Can't believe I don't find a dupe.. If someone has it, let me know.

Comment: [Spread syntax readout : Only for iterables.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Only_for_iterables)

Comment: @Kaiido You might remember https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370046/1048572?

Comment: @Bergi, no I didn't remember a question in particular, just found very unlikely that it hadn't been asked already (well actually [I saw one already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49103692/using-es6-spread-operator-on-file-object), but even then didn't answered thinking there must be a dupe, that I probably didn't have time to search back then).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because the [spread syntax in object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) "*copies own enumerable properties from a provided object onto a new object*".

None of the *own properties* of your Error object are *enumerable*.

```js
var error = new Error('error');
var props = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(error);
console.log(props); // none of these are enumerable
```

So the spread syntax copies nothing. If it had an enumerable value, then it would have copied it:

```js
var error = new Error('error');
error.foo = 'bar';
console.log({...error});
```