# Destructure all properties for Error object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to extract all properties from an Error instance by doing.

```js
const test = new Error('hi there');
console.log({...test});  // empty object (I expected name + message)
console.log(test.message);  // "hi there"
console.log(test.hasOwnProperty("message"));  // True
```

Why is it not possible to destructure the `message` property from the Error instance in a new object?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the reason for not spread (es 6 spread operator) javascript Error object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53167026/what-is-the-reason-for-not-spread-es-6-spread-operator-javascript-error-object)

Answer (score 0):

The properties of an Error instance are not *enumerable*, which means they won't participate in the spread syntax extraction, or in `for ... in` etc.