# How to retain file input value after drag and drop?

Tags: javascript, html, filelist

Here is the code I use to drag and drop multiple files:

`document.getElementById('file-input').files = e.dataTransfer.files;`

This works, but how can I retain the old value after a second drag and drop?

I tried combining both arrays but the FileList is read only. I could try:

`let newFile = new File()`

But I cannot not find any documentation on how to properly to do so.

Answer (score 0):

To save all your files (old and new), you need a server because you cannot save in the browser (front-end). If you want to do this **temporarily**, then you must avoid page refreshes, one solution is to add `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: Thanks, I am already using `event.preventDefault();` and I am not refreshing the page. During the drag and drop, the files are saved to input[File] via JavaScript.

Comment: What you can do is use the `localStorage` and you can see useful information here: “https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19119040/how-do-i-save-and-restore-a-file-object-in-local-storage” Although my recommendation is to use a server.