# How to store a File object to local storage and retrieve it

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, local-storage

I am converting a blob image to a File object, uploading to local storage and retrieving it, but when i retrieve it the file object isn't in the format i expect.

I am converting a blob image to a file object like so:

```
async function convertBlobUrlToFile(image, filename, fileType) {
  const response = await fetch(image);
  const blobData = await response.blob();
  const uploadFileImage = new File([blobData], filename, { type: fileType });
  return uploadFileImage;
}
```

and uploading it to local storage like so:

```
convertBlobUrlToFile(croppedImage, imageFileName, fileType).then((blobObject) => {
        localStorage.setItem('croppedImage', blobObject);
 }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error)
})
```

which looks like a normal file object, an example is

```
File {name: 'ProfilePic.jpg', lastModified: 1679604282406, lastModifiedDate: Thu Mar 23 
      2023 20:44:42 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 600329, …}
```

however when i retrieve it, it just says
`[object File]`

I try to use `JSON.parse` to see if anything changes but i don't have much luck.

Can someone help me in trying to store the File object into local storage correctly please so when i do `localStorage.getItem()` it is an actual File object like the example above.

Thank you for anyone helping :)

Comment: Try using indexeddb.

Comment: Does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19119040/how-do-i-save-and-restore-a-file-object-in-local-storage

Comment: Thanks everyone.

That link did help.

The answer was the convert to base64, store in local storage then convert to file object to read it or pass it somewhere else